# AWS EventBridge customize event pattern

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I want to send the event pattern with customized values as follows.

```
{
  "source": ["aws.ecr"],
  "detail-type": ["ECR Image Action"],
  "detail": {
    "action-type": ["PUSH", "DELETE"],
    "result": ["SUCCESS"],
    "git-repository-name": ["github-api-test"], <-- custom
    "file-path": ["bin/imgtag.json"]  <-- custom
  }
}
```

I want to get these values out of Lambda and use them as follows.

```js
const handler = async (event, context) => {
   const { detail } = event;
   const filePath = detail['file-path'];
   const gitRepoName = detail['git-repository-name'];
}
```

However, if you put the customized value(file-path, git-repository-name) in the event pattern, the event will not work.

Please tell me how to use it as above.

Answer (score 0):

I found this anwser.

First, click **Edit rule**,

**Select targets > configure input > input transformer**

Fill it out as follows. (**$.detail** is one of the data that comes over when an ECR event occurs.)

[image]

And then parse the event in the **lambda function** as follows.

```js
const handler = async (event, context) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(event);
    const gitRepoName = data['git-repository-name'];
    const filePath = data['file-path'];
    console.log(gitRepoName, filePath);
};
```

console log output

```
github-api-test, bin/imgtag.json
```